# Drop caps in pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdf, latex, pdf-generation, typography

I want to find a way to produce drop caps (large initial letters several lines high) in pdfLaTeX. I know that there is a `dropping` package which works well when used with `latex` + `dvips`. However, when used with `pdflatex` the result looks ugly.

My source file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% for pdflatex file.tex # dropping is ugly
% \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% \usepackage[pdftex]{dropping}

% for latex file.tex ; dvips -T 12cm,8cm file.dvi # dropping is OK
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dropping}

\usepackage[papersize={12cm,8cm},
    left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,
    top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\dropping[-3pt]{3}{W}ith a drop cap, the initial sits within the margins and
runs several lines deep into the paragraph, pushing some normal-sized text off
these lines. This keeps the left and top margins of the paragraph flush.
In~modern browsers, this can be done with a combination of HTML and CSS
by~using the float: left; setting.
\end{document}
```

When I compile it as

```
latex drop.tex && dvips -T 12cm,8cm drop.dvi
```

the result is OK:

[image: dropping-latex-dvips]

When I uncomment `[pdftex]` lines and compile it as

```
pdflatex drop.tex
```

the results is:

[image: dropping-pdflatex]

Can anyone suggest a better way to produce drop caps with `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thank you very much for quick responces! Actually, both comments by hop and Charlie Martin were useful. `lettrine.sty` is a fantastic package, and it works *if* scaleable fonts are used.

So, the solution was to force Type 1 CM fonts instead of default CM *and* use `lettrine.sty`. `lettrine.sty` documentation suggests to `\usepackage{type1cm}`.

This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% works with pdfLaTeX
\usepackage{type1cm} % scalable fonts
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage[papersize={12cm,4cm},
    left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,
    top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=3,slope=-4pt,nindent=-4pt]{W}{ith} a drop cap, the initial sits
within the margins and runs several lines deep into the paragraph, pushing some
normal-sized text off these lines. This keeps the left and top margins of the
paragraph flush.  In~modern browsers, this can be done with a combination of
HTML and CSS by~using the float: left; setting.
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: pdflatex-type1cm-lettrine]

Thank you!

PS. `dropping` does not work correctly even with `type1cm`.

**UPD.** This example also works with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 6):

Try another font, one with scaling; this looks like the PDF isn't finding a big enough font for the cap-W and is substituting.  The other option is to use a dvi-to-PDF translation.

Answer (score 4):

[lettrine.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lettrine/)

Comment: I suspect that won't help.  The W is dropping fine -- baseline moved down -- but it's not a big enough character.

Comment: dropping is known to not work nicely with pdflatex. if lettrine doesn't work for him, i'll withdraw this answer.

Answer (score 3):

As [jetxee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413954/drop-caps-in-pdflatex#414091) mentioned, it is necessary to use a scalable font in order to get exactly the right size for the initial. If you change the font from the default, this will occur without you having to do anything.

For historical reasons, the default CM fonts are loaded to "snap" to specific sizes, rather than being load-able at any scaled size. This is from the time when the original Metafont sources were used, when a different font size changed the actual shape of the glyphs (Google *optical sizes* for the curious).

The canonical solution to fix this problem with the CM fonts is to load the `fix-cm` package. The package `type1cm` is an older package that basically does the same thing.